# Caldera Debian Keyboard Output Chinese Characters

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-layout

So, I'm an involuntary IT guy at my current position, and we have come across an issue with Caldera's flavor of Debian Linux. For some reason, with no real prompting, our keyboard starting typing chinese characters instead of English. In addition, all UPPERCASE characters are still in English.

Looking at the keyboard layout setting, it is still set to English (United States). Looking into /etc/default/keyboard , the setting is set to English, with no option for Chinese. Ditto /etc/default/locale.

In the meantime, we are able to type in all caps, but this issue has happened a few times.

Two questions: How do we fix it? How do we prevent it from happening again?

We are worried about logging out or restarting the computer, because if we log out and the character encoding remains Chinese, we will be unable to login to this computer, and it is a mission critical printer server. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow Caldera? Blast from the past there. Are you actually running Caldera Linux or are you running the software called Caldera on the Debian operating system? What's the kernel version (command is `uname -r`)?

Comment: OK I guess I should've read the question more closely it looks like you are talking about [the printer software](http://www.caldera.com/support/table-of-compatibilites/) and not the defunct Linux distribution.

Comment: You might use the `env` command to see if there's some environmental variable getting set that it changing the shell's locale. for instance `LANG=ru_RU.utf8` makes some of my shell switch over to Russian.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for the late response. We are definitely talking about the printer software :) As far as I can tell, everywhere that I've looked is set to English. Also it's hard to run the env command, because the keyboard types in Chinese :/

Comment: Geez, I don't know. If you can't run commands with lower case letters you're kind of hosed since that's virtually anything you could possibly want to run. Did they install a GUI on this machine and is it running? It sounds like a software appliance, does Caldera give you guys support for this stuff? They may have some sort of tool that can manage locales and something got changed in that.

Comment: How are you verifying those files if you can't type and commands in?

Comment: I found a workaround for running the commands that is very difficult to use, but still can let me eventually get lowercase commands. The env command did return just English. It sounds like a bug in the install, as Caldera printing installs their own version of Debian on our machine, and it's probably a problem with their version of Debian. We might just have to give them a call I guess :/ Thanks for the help